# Syntastic going passive mode

Tags: vim, syntastic

It's been quite some time that I'm facing this annoying problem with syntastic.

When running gvim and performing a `SyntasticInfo c`, without opening anything, it returns me :

```
Syntastic version: 3.5.0-72
Info for filetype: c
Mode: active
Filetype c is active
Available checkers: clang_check gcc make
Currently enabled checker: clang_check
```

But as soon as I open a `c` file and do a `SyntasticInfo` I get:

```
Syntastic version: 3.5.0-72
Info for filetype: c
Mode: active
Passive filetype: c
Filetype c is passive
Available checkers: clang_check gcc make
Currently enabled checker: clang_check
```

As a result nothing is checked.

Here is what is in my vimrc :

```
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_c_checkers = ['clang_check']
let g:syntastic_c_clang_post_args = ""
let g:syntastic_mode_map={"mode":"active", "active_filetypes": [], "passive_filetypes": []}
```

[Edit]
Having tried to put `'c'` for `active_filetypes`, it doesn't change anything. Though, what is really weird, is that the active checking is not triggered if I don't do a `:so ~/.vimrc` and every time I open gvim. It's as if this option wasn't taken into account by gvim. 
[/Edit]

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Eclim installed.  Eclim silently disables syntastic for the filetypes it can handle.  Recent versions of syntastic warn you when this situation is detected.